# How can the menu stay still when you hover?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ebepwj1m/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>MENIU 1</li>
    <li>MENIU 2</li>
    <li>MENIU 3</li>
    <li>MENIU 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li:hover{
    border-left:5px solid red;
}
```

My problem is simple ... when you put the arrow on the menu, the menu item moves a few pixels in right.

How can I prevent it from moving?

EDIT:

Perhaps I did not explain well ... I do not want another rim ... just when you put an item in the list arrow appears red headboard and my text goes in the right

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ebepwj1m/1/ Is that what you want?

Comment: People are suggesting the transparent border method, which is fine, but you might as well write that like this: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ebepwj1m/3/)

Comment: If _any one_ of you answerers would explain the problem and why your solution works I would upvote you. "Here's the cure" with **no** explanation is _not_ an answer to a question.

Comment: Marius, if you don't want to add a padding on the left side, it becomes slightly more complex. [You could use `:before` for that](https://jsfiddle.net/ebepwj1m/5/). Not sure if this is what you meant with the arrow, but I'm sure you can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding some space that is not there before, that`s causing the selected item to move right. All you need to do is to add a transparent border, when item is not on hover.

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li{border-left:5px solid transparent;}
ul li:hover{border-left:5px solid red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting default trasparent border:

```
ul li {border: 5px solid transparent;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The menu `li`s are moving because you are *adding* a 5px border where there was none before.  This increases the size of your overall box and shifts it to the right to make room for the border.

You can cure this by having a 5px border all the time, but make it transparent until hovered, so the 5px is always there and the box won't shift.

Just add a CSS rule for the li when not hovered:

```
ul li {
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add a transparent border.

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li{border-left:5px solid transparent;}
ul li:hover{
    border-left:5px solid red;
}
```

working demo https://jsfiddle.net/geekrose/ebepwj1m/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add a default transparent border to the li's:

`ul li{ border-left:5px solid transparent }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi now you can used to padding as like this

```
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li{padding-left:5px;}
ul li:hover{
    border-left:5px solid red;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Demo Example

```css
ul {list-style-type:none;}
ul li{padding-left:5px;}
ul li:hover{
    border-left:5px solid red;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>MENIU 1</li>
    <li>MENIU 2</li>
    <li>MENIU 3</li>
    <li>MENIU 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add transparent border to the ul li class.

```
ul li{
border-left: 5px solid transparent;  
}
```

following will be your final css

```
ul {list-style-type:none; }
ul li{
border-left: 5px solid transparent;  
}
ul li:hover{
border-left:5px solid red;
}
```